# Make an IN statement using two attributes in Activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, where-in

I've been trying this for a while, and can't seem to get it right in Activerecord.

Given an array of `asset_id` and `asset_type` pairs, query a class that has both those attributes, only where both `asset_id` and `asset_type` match.

So given the array

`[[4,"Logo"],[1,"Image"]]`

I want to generate the SQL

`SELECT "asset_attachments".* FROM "asset_attachments" WHERE ((asset_id,asset_type) IN ((4,'Logo'),(1,'Image')))`

I can do this by manually entering a string using where like this:

`AssetAttachment.where("(asset_id,asset_type) IN ((4,'Logo'),(1,'Image'))")`

But I'm trying to use it with an array of any length and asset type/id.

So far I've tried

`AssetAttachment.where([:asset_id, :asset_type] => [[4,"Logo"],[1,"Image"]])`

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for [:asset_id, :asset_type]:Array ``

and

`AssetAttachment.where("(asset_id,asset_type)" => [[4,"Logo"],[1,"Image"]])`

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column asset_attachments.(asset_id,asset_type) does not exist`

and

`AssetAttachment.where("(asset_id,asset_type) IN (?,?)",[[4,"Logo"],[1,"Image"]])`

`ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: (asset_id,asset_type) IN (?,?)`

Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to make use of PG specific functionality in ActiveRecord. Generally speaking, most ORMs provide a least-common-denominator interface for functionality shared between supported databases, so I don't think this is possible, at least in rails 3. Rails 4 is supposed to have an improved PG adapter, which may allow for PG dependent functionality like this, so that may be worth a look.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have as much experience with SQL, but I would have thought that this is not an uncommon type of query. Is this not possible in vanilla SQL?

Answer (score 1):

#### set vs. array

The core of the problem is: you are mixing **sets** and **arrays** in an impossible way.

`elem IN (...)` .. expects a *set*.
`elem = ANY(...)` .. expects an *array*.

You can use [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to transform an array to a set.
You can use the [aggregate function `array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) to transform a set to an array.

#### Errors

Here, you are trying to form an *array* from `(asset_id, asset_type)`:

> ```
> AssetAttachment.where([:asset_id, :asset_type] => [[4,"Logo"],[1,"Image"]])
> ```

.. which is impossible, since arrays have to consist of identical types, while we obviously deal with a numeric and a string constant (you kept the actual types a secret).

Here, you force `"(asset_id, asset_type)"` as *single column name* by double-quoting it:

> ```
> AssetAttachment.where("(asset_id,asset_type)" => [[4,"Logo"],[1,"Image"]])
> ```

And finally, here you try provide a *single* bind variable for two `?`:

> ```
> AssetAttachment.where("(asset_id,asset_type) IN (?,?)",[[4,"Logo"],[1,"Image"]])
> ```

#### Valid SQL

In pure SQL, either of these work:

```
SELECT * FROM asset_attachments
WHERE  (asset_id, asset_type) IN ((4, 'Logo'), (1, 'Image'));

SELECT * FROM asset_attachments
WHERE  (asset_id, asset_type) IN (VALUES(4, 'Logo'), (1, 'Image'));

SELECT * FROM asset_attachments
WHERE  (asset_id, asset_type) = ANY (ARRAY[(4, 'Logo'), (1, 'Image')]);
```

If you have a *long* list of possible matches, an explicit `JOIN` would prove faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   asset_attachments
JOIN   (VALUES(4, 'Logo'), (1, 'Image')) AS v(asset_id, asset_type)
                                       USING (asset_id, asset_type)
```

#### Valid syntax for AR

I am an expert with Postgres, with AR not so much. This simple form might work:

```
AssetAttachment.where("(asset_id,asset_type) IN ((?,?),(?,?))", 4,"Logo",1,"Image")
```

Not sure if this could work, not sure about single or double quotes either:

```
AssetAttachment.where((:asset_id, :asset_type) => [(4,'Logo'),(1,'Image')])
```